# generating traffic from arbitrary source IP address to localhost

Tags: linux, network-programming, tcp, raw-sockets

On my own Linux server (well, an EC2 instance) on which I have root, I would like to issue HTTP requests to a process running on the same server, but make it think the request is coming from an arbitrary IP address, to test an IP whitelist.

I think I understand how to do it fully manually, using raw sockets. But I would like to use something ready-made. It seems to me such a requirement is not unique to me. What tool do other people use?